# I receive an error when trying to pass a component/prop into a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vagrant, components, prop

I'm new to react, so this is likely a beginner's error.

Here's my code that I'm working on: https://github.com/tylerehc/hrs/

It runs fine in that version--that is, the browser renders 'hello cow'.

However, when I try to use a second component and pass in a prop, I receive this error:

[image]

I am trying to pass in a prop by replacing

```
return(<div>hello cow</div>);
```

with

```
return(<ProfileHeader body='test' />);
```

ProfileHeader.js looks like this:

```
class ProfileHeader extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.prop.body}</div>);
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: {this.prop.body} should be 'props'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rename `this.prop` to `this.props`

```
class ProfileHeader extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.props.body}</div>);
  }
}

class Profile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        hello cow
        <ProfileHeader body='hello' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Profile />, document.getElementById('profile')
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one js file? Or does it have to all be in one?

Comment: Is it possible, but better you must check webpack or browserify that lets you require('modules') in the browser by bundling up all of your dependencies.